# How to move move selected items from one C1List to another in C#?

Tags: c#

C1List component is something similar to listBox. I have button and event for that button:

```
private void btnNavigateLeft_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  if (lbRight.SelectedIndex != -1)
  {
    lbLeft.InsertItem();

    lbRight.RemoveItem(lbRight.SelectedIndex);
  }
}
```

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Loop through the selected items, add them to the second list.  Then remove them from the first.

Comment: Read the vendor's documentation?

Comment: cant you clone the list and use this to populate the second list?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
lst_2.Items.Add(lst_1.SelectedItem);
lst_1.Items.Remove(lst_1.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, c1 list component doesn't have Items.Remove() method... and RemoveItems() doesn't working.

Comment: I think it will be List. Are they labels or what are they?

Comment: No, c1 list is something similar to listBox, but it doesn't have same properties. It is not label.